# Where is the most remote convenience store in Taiwan?

Tags: factoids, taiwan, remote-locations

Anyone who has travelled around Taiwan by scooter, bike, hitchhiking, or on foot, will know the value of the welcoming convenience store chains. They almost always have a generously sized area where people can sit, rest, chat, and eat the snacks they buy. At least one that I know of is used as an informal overnight stop by locals on round-island bike tours.

Typical FamilyMart on the east coast showing its bicycle-tour theme and outdoor seating area:
[image: A cyclist-friendly FamilyMart in Taiwan]

The one I mentioned where people spend the night is 55km before the next one. That's a huge distance in the place that has one of the highest ratios of convenience stores to population. (But it's only 700 from the one pictured, so can't be the most remote.)

This has got me wondering if there's a chain convenience store somewhere in Taiwan that's truly remote? Perhaps somewhere in the interior?

I'm intending to spend three months in Taiwan in a few months and as before, the convenience stores will be an important part of my trip, especially when actually on the road covering distance. So I think it will make a fun challenge to visit the most remote one on the island.

For the sake of this question, I'm only including the chains and not every independent small shop. So that's probably 7-Eleven, FamilyMart, Hi-Life, and OK Mart if the industry hasn't changed since my last visit. And I include only the main island.

To be perfectly clear, I'm looking for the chain convenience store with the longest road distance to its nearest other convenience store.

Comment: Does it count if the location is very remote but has two convenience stores one next to the other? (as in the example in your photo)

Comment: @JonathanReez: Not as an answer but as extra info it would be interesting. Just because I have to have a rule and this is how I was thinking and how I tried to word it.

Comment: Who would open a convenience store in a remote location? They need customers, lots of them.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I don't know. But I'm having another conversation with a guy on Quora who seems to think most of Taiwan's east coast is "remote" so that's all subjective and by his standards I've been to dozens of remote ones already. By the criteria in my question though there can be no subjectivity, even if the most remove one is not what you would consider remote, it will still be the most remote.

Comment: Non-example: Lishan, Taichung is properly remote (without any settlements nearby), but there is a 7-eleven and a Family Mart in that town of few thousand, which excludes each other from the question.

Comment: My casual search suggests the 7-eleven in Namaxia, Kaohsiung may be a viable candidate, partly because the settlement is on a dead-end. 33 km on a main road to the 7-eleven in Jiaxian, Kaohsiung or 30 km on a minor road to the 7-eleven in Dapu, Chiayi which I am not even sure if it is passible or not. Leaving it as a comment as I intend to do further research when I have the time.

Comment: Nanshan is one that comes to mind, but there are both a 7-11 and Family Mart now, so it doesn't count.

Comment: @martin: Yes it's a shame when I was hunting on Google Maps almost all of the ones in the middle of nowhere had a nearby competitor from the other chain! I might visit some of those too anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Does **no** road connection to another convenience store count too?

There are two Outlying Islands which have just a single convenience store: 東莒 Dongju and 綠島 Green Island.

1. The [7-11 on 綠島 Green Island](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/4298727463) is [32.15 km](https://boulter.com/gps/distance/?from=22.6680735%2C+121.4684898&to=22.7913518%2C+121.1851617&units=k) from the [nearest one in 臺東 Taitung](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/4360116593).
2. The [7-11 on 東莒 Dongju](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/9206593917) is [21.65 kilometers](https://boulter.com/gps/distance/?from=25.9600459%2C+119.9731120&to=26.1528648%2C+119.9378233&units=k) from the closest [Family Mart on 南竿 Nangan](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/10201933168).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Actually I expected there would be several on islands here and there and thought that would make it less like one right answer so I included this rule to cover that in my question: `And I include only the main island.` Thanks though! (For instance, it looks like Dongyin Island also has only one 7-Eleven)